# initialization variable changed in each iteration in a for clause

Tags: c, variables, initialization

A passed parameter was changed in the middle of the code without changing or manipulating the variable

I launched a C program with this command:

```
anonymous DELAI_ANONYME=O sanspm=O
```

The main function code is below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
  EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    SQL100 qstrRefIndiv = {0};
    int qiCheckIndiv = 0;
    SQL20 qstrTrigStatus = {0};
  EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

  char strLogName[100] = {0};
  char strRef[100] = {0};
  int iNoCommit = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int iDelCase=0;
  char strDelai[1];
  char strSanspm[1];
  strcpy(strDelai, "N");  
  strcpy(strSanspm, "N");  
  char selectcof[1000]= {0};
  initscr();
  bkg_init();

  for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
  {
    refresh();
    db_log_message (LL_INFO, "Iter Nbr= [%d]\n", i);

    if(strcmp(argv[i],"NOCOMMIT")==0)
    {
      iNoCommit = 1;
    }
    if(strncmp(argv[i], "ref=", 4)==0)
    {
       strcpy(strRef,&argv[i][4]);
       strcpy (qstrRefIndiv, strRef);
       db_log_message (LL_INFO, "ref param= [%s]\n", qstrRefIndiv);
    }
    if(strncmp(argv[i], "DELAI_ANONYME=", 14)==0)
    {
       strcpy(strDelai,&argv[i][14]); 
       db_log_message (LL_INFO, "ref Delai= [%s]\n", strDelai);
    } 
    if(strncmp(argv[i], "delcase=", 8)==0)
    {
       iDelCase=atoi(&argv[i][8]);
       db_log_message (LL_INFO, "ref iDelCase= [%s]\n", iDelCase);
    }
    if(strncmp(argv[i], "sanspm=", 7)==0)
    {
       db_log_message (LL_INFO, "[sanspm] before ref Delai= [%s]\n", strDelai);
       strcpy(strSanspm,&argv[i][7]);
       db_log_message (LL_INFO, "ref strSanspm= [%s]\n", strSanspm);
       db_log_message (LL_INFO, "[sanspm] after ref Delai= [%s]\n", strDelai);
    }
  }

  db_log_message (LL_INFO, "ref Delai 1= [%s]\n", strDelai);
  db_log_message (LL_INFO, "ref strSanspm 1= [%s]\n", strSanspm);
  ...
  endwin();
  return(0);
}
```

After checking the log file I see that the DELAI_ANONYME variable was changed in the middel of the for clause as shown in the logs after launching the program

Log:

```
[INFO ] [    0.017] Iter Nbr= [1]
[INFO ] [    0.000] ref Delai= [O]
[INFO ] [    0.000] Iter Nbr= [2]
[INFO ] [    0.000] [sanspm] before ref Delai= [O]
[INFO ] [    0.000] ref strSanspm= [O]
[INFO ] [    0.000] [sanspm] after ref Delai= []
[INFO ] [    0.000] ref Delai 1= []
[INFO ] [    0.000] ref strSanspm 1= [O]
```

When I changed the order of the parameters I got the below behavior with this command:

```
anonymous sanspm=O DELAI_ANONYME=O
```

I see the DELAI_ANONYME variable is OK but at the same time strSanspm variable is taking another character that is not initialized at the beginning 'OO'

Log:

```
[INFO ] [    0.001] Iter Nbr= [1]
[INFO ] [    0.000] [sanspm] before ref Delai= []
[INFO ] [    0.000] ref strSanspm= [O]
[INFO ] [    0.000] [sanspm] after ref Delai= []
[INFO ] [    0.000] Iter Nbr= [2]
[INFO ] [    0.000] ref Delai= [O]
[INFO ] [    0.000] ref Delai 1= [O]
[INFO ] [    0.000] ref strSanspm 1= [OO]
```

Comment: strDelai is too small to hold anything but an empty string.

Comment: You have a couple `char` arrays of length 1.  Do you understand that the only valid index into those arrays is 0, and that they can only hold a single character?  So if you want to store a null-terminated string into them, it will have to be the empty string (as Mat pointed out)?